# Mistake with NULL comparison in C

Tags: c

Could you say me what mistake I'm doing here? When I set `url = NULL` then compare whether it has NULL whether by `if(strlen(url)!=0)` or by `if(url!=NULL)` the program crashes or breaks up. I know it's very a simple thing but I'm doing something wrong.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char* url="/v1.0/fafffsdf"  ;
    url=NULL;
    printf("%s\n",url);
    if(url!=0)
    {
        printf("It ain't NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It's NULL\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting confused between the NULL character which is `\0` and NULL which indicates a NULL pointer?

Comment: A minor nit, the null character when abbreviated is `NUL` with one L. Which I presume is handy to avoid confusion with the `NULL` macro. I'm not sure which came first (*ASCII 1963, C 1972...I guess I have my answer*). And I'm not sure which is more or less confusing.

Answer (score 11):

The crash is in

```
printf("%s\n",url);
```

The pointer is pointing to `NULL` and you are trying to read from there, effectively dereferencing a `NULL` pointer which will generate a [segmentation fault](http://ideone.com/lcQbW).

Pointing to an empty string like

```
char *url = "";
```

is OK and quite different from pointing to a NULL location like

```
char *url =NULL;
```

which is dangerous if dereferenced.

An empty string has a valid location in memory and can be dereferenced. Its just that it has nothing in it expect a `\0`.

Comment: For preference I'd say "empty string" rather than "null string". Calling different things by the name "null" is what causes this confusion in the first place.